# State Provider isnt updating the ui, when i set a new state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to save a list of objects in a riverpod provider. When I add or remove one of the objects, the displayed list should update. However, a new value is stored in the state, but the UI does not update. I have already read all the resources I can think of, but none of the solutions available work for me.

My Code:
Provider with state:

```
final objectProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => ObjectState());

class ObjectState extends StateNotifier<List<Object>>{
  ObjectState() : super([]);

  void add(Object object) {
    // state.add(object);
    // state = state;
    state = [...state, object];
  }

  void remove(Object object) {
    // state.remove(object);
    // state = state;
    state = state.where((Object object) => object != object).toList();
  }
}
```

My Class, that wants to read the Provider:

```
class CreateSomething extends ConsumerWidget {
  CreateSomething({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  var ingredients = ref.watch(ingredientsProvider.notifier).state; //on state there is a Warning: The member 'state' can only be used within 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart' or a test.
  
  return screen();
}

Widget screen() {
    return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
      Card(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              const Text("Add new Object"),
              const Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref.read(objectProvider.notifier).state.add(Object(name: ""));
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: objectList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return objectCard(objectList[index]);
              }))
    ]);
  }
```

The funny thing is that I have a code block above it that outputs a route argument and enters the information into the ui. This works perfectly. however, if I want to replicate this, it no longer works. i use the line `ref.read(objectProvider.notifier).state.add(element);` and it works and even updates the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason you have a warning on line:

```
  var ingredients = ref.watch(ingredientsProvider.notifier).state;
```

Doing `ref.watch(p.notifier).state` will not listen to state changes. That's by design, as you're instead obtaining the notifier itself, not its state.

Do:

```dart
  var ingredients = ref.watch(ingredientsProvider);
```

Comment: this seems good and seems to work for the add and remove function of the state, but how can i obtain th list so show it in the ui?

Comment: "ingredients" is the list!

Comment: Oh ok i got confused because it got shown as "Object?", but i guess i just have to cast it propperly then.